# jQuery 1.8.2 on command not working like live command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I just upgrade my jQuery library to  1.8.2 and changed like below code.

`$(document).on('change','#frmLocations #cboSearch',function(event){
    });`

But when I dynamically add some DOM like "table" with click events , change invents  its not working properly. But when I put "live" command ,it's working properly. so please help me to replace "live" command from "ON" command.
Actually now I am tired with this.

Please check this link , when I click on first and second text box, alert should be  "third",
but not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/6TcPA/4/

```
  $(function(){
    $('div').append(
        '<input  id="first"/><input id="second"/>'
    );

    $(document).on('click','#first',function(event){
        $('#second').attr('id','third');
    });

    $(document).on('click','#second',function(event){
        alert("second");
    });

    $(document).on('click','#third',function(event){
        alert("third");
    });

    $(document).on('click','#third',function(event){
        alert("third");
    });
});
```

Now 2 alerts ("third") will appear.

Comment: please mention your html also so that we can see if the problem with that or not.

Comment: will you please elaborate 'not working properly'? add some relevant code also.

Comment: Do you mean for the selector to be `'#frmLocations #cboSearch'` or `'#frmLocations, #cboSearch'`?  The second one will target two different objects, the first only one particular object.  If we saw your actual HTML that you're  trying to target, we could help better.

Comment: please post HyperText .

Comment: **"But when I dynamically add some DOM like "table" with click events"** do you want event on `click`? try with `on('click'`

Comment: @jogesh_pi what if "frmLocations " is Select Dropdown ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi it is **#frmLocations #cboSearch** means **#cboSearch** element under **#frmLocations**??

Comment: actually it's a big ERP , cannot upload it here, sorry for that. my system is working on ajax in index.php file. when I click menu on index.php , generate a ajax and get program code and put it in to the index.php (jquery.html()) . so javascript file is already include in index.php file. its not come with ajax form. so "on" command not recognize events. but when I put live command , working correct.

Comment: I want to check any event , in this case "chang" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use comma to separate event for separate IDs.Use following

Update according to OP's requirement and New [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TcPA/7/)

```
$(function(){
    $('div').append(
        '<input id="first"/><input id="second"/>'
    );

    $('#first').on('click',function(){
       $('#second').attr('id','third');

    });

    $('#second').bind('click',function(){
        alert("third");
    });

});
```

OR u can do it this way also [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TcPA/8/)

```
$(function(){
    $('div').append(
        '<input id="first"/><input id="second"/>'
    );

    $('#first').on('click',function(){
       $('#second').attr('id','third');

        $('#third').bind('click',function(){
            alert("third");
        });

    });            
});
```

old one:

```
$(document).on('change','#frmLocations , #cboSearch',function(event){
});
```

You can check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_sel.asp) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) its working.

Comment: please check this link , when i click on first and second text box, alert should be  "third".
but not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/6TcPA/4/

//html
<div>
    
</div>

//javascript
$(function(){
    $('div').append(
        '<input id="first"/><input id="second"/>'
    );
    
    $(document).on('click','#first',function(event){
        $('#second').prop('id') = 'third';
    });
    
    $(document).on('click','#second',function(event){
        alert("second");
    });
    
    $(document).on('click','#third',function(event){
        alert("third");
    });
    
});

Comment: @RoshanPerera , check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6TcPA/7/  . It changes ID of original div (TWO => THREE) . But event does not change. So assign event Click to element with id "two", But Even if id gets changed to "three" ,  event (click) remains same on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#first,#second',function(event){
        alert("sdfdsf");
    });
```

Instead of:

```
$(document).on('click','#first #second',function(event){ //wrong id should be comma seprated
        alert("sdfdsf");
    });
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6TcPA/1/)**

**Note:** If dynamic content is `select box` then you can use change `event` and if its `input` you can use `keyup` event. If i could see your markup then able to give more specific answer.